# reading cell as "cell coordinate" (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have written "a5" in B2, I'd like writing A1:B2, with B2 linking to its cell value, the actual result should be A1:A5.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a function which outputs a cell coordinate, then I have to use this cell coordinate in other function throughout the sheet. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Sorry, the question is still very vague and not described properly.

Comment: Have you looked into [indirect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter into A1 the formula:
`=INDIRECT(B2)`
Enter into B2: "A5"
Enter anything into A5. This will display in A1 as described.

In VBA:

```
Function FakeIndirect(address as String)
    FakeIndirect = Range(address).value
End Function
```

Comment: thx, it works, another small question: what if "a5" is on sheet2? I mean, I would like to have the result on sheet1 while calling an array on sheet2...Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!INDIRECT(Sheet2!B2) seems not to work (neither with parentheses).

Comment: Since INDIRECT just changes the address string into a cell reference, you would need stuff like A1: =SUM(INDIRECT(B2)), with "sheet2!A1:A5" entered in B2. Now A1 will be the sum of sheet 2 range A1:A5. Please press F1-button in Excel and type indirect to read more.